# Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^ _Nullable)(enum MyReturnCode)' to parameter of type 'void (^)(enum MyReturnCode)'

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, clang, clang++

In Objective-C (Xcode 11.3.1), I have two methods receiving a block pointer as their argument:

```
- (void)showDialog:(void (^ _Nullable)(enum MyReturnCode returnCode))handler;

- (void)openFile:(void (^ _Nullable)(BOOL success))handler;

typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyReturnCode)
{
    MyReturnCodeFirstOption,
    MyReturnCodeSecondOption
};
```

The methods are called as follows:

```
[self showDialog:^(enum MyReturnCode returnCode) {}];
[self openFile:^(BOOL success) {}];
```

If I try to compile it I get an error on the line calling `showDialog`:

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^ _Nullable)(enum MyReturnCode)' 
                    to parameter of type 'void (^)(enum MyReturnCode)'
```

If I try to remove the `_Nullable` from the method definition, I get an error where both parts as equal:

```
Incompatible block pointer types sending 'void (^)(enum MyReturnCode)'
                    to parameter of type 'void (^)(enum MyReturnCode)'
```

Calls to the `openFile` method are compiled without any issues.

Why I'm getting the error on the `showDialog` call? 
Why not on `openFile` where the only difference is the handler return type? 
How to fix that?

Comment: `[self showDialog:^(enum MyReturnCode returnCode) {}];` remove word `enum`

Comment: @Cy-4AH The compiler does not think so. Still reporting an error.

Comment: also from method prototype

Comment: That compiles. How it is with using of the enum in the method definition? The tutorials I found has told me I should use the enum keyword in method definitions. So I'm quite confused :/

Comment: I think your's tutorial wasn't using modern syntax with `NS_ENUM` macro.